# Required regions for a theme

Tags: 7

Are there a set of required regions for a theme that they must have?

I thought I read this in the documentation at one point, but I can't find it again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described in [$closure becomes $page_bottom, new $page_top and hidden regions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/upgrading-6x-themes-to-7x#closure), the required regions are:

- content
- help
- page_top
- page_bottom

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to declare any regions in your custom themes. While it is true that there are a couple of mandatory regions (especially regions[content]), drupal provides default regions when these are not declared:

http://drupal.org/node/171205#regions
going more in depth on this page http://drupal.org/node/171224

there are some comments discussing the page_top and page_bottom region which nicoz mentioned.
http://drupal.org/node/171205#comment-5132804

Answer (score 1):

If a theme doesn't define any region, Drupal assumes the theme is using the following regions:

- header
- highlighted
- help
- content
- sidebar_first
- sidebar_second
- footer

If by *required* you mean *required to be defined*, then none of the regions must be defined, but in that case Drupal assumes the theme has a set of predefined regions.
If by *required* you mean *required to have*, then that is the *content* region, as reported in [Theming Drupal 7 / Writing theme .info files / regions](https://www.drupal.org/node/171205#regions).

> If you override regions in Drupal 7, you are obliged to declare the line `regions[content] = Content`.